# Query a column containing Comma Separated String

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having an issue with an `sql` query. Basically I have this method:

```
public function loadByDirectoryContact($directoryContact,$type='') 
    {
        global $db;
        $t = 'directoryprogramme';
        $query  = 'SELECT c.* FROM `'.$t.'` c ';
        $query .= 'WHERE `c`.`presenters` = '.$directoryContact->getId().' ';
        $query .= 'OR `c`.`staff` = '.$directoryContact->getId().' ';
        if($type!=""){
            $query .=" AND c.type='".$type."' ";
        }


        $query .= QueryBuilder::orderBy('name','asc');

        echo $query; die();

        $db->query($query,$t);

        while($db->next($t))
        {
            $node = new Programme();
            $node->setId($db->get('id',$t));
            $node->setName($db->get('name',$t));
            $node->setBroadcastTime($db->get('broadcast_time',$t));
            $node->setDescription($db->get('description',$t));
            $node->setDays($db->get('days',$t));
            $node->setSubjects($db->get('subjects', $t));
            $node->setStaff($db->get('staff',$t));
            $node->setPresenters($db->get('presenters',$t));
            $directoryCompany = new DirectoryCompany($db->get('directorycompany_id',$t));
            $node->setDirectoryCompany($directoryCompany);
            $node->setContributors($directoryContact);
            $node->setType($db->get('type',$t));
            $this->nodes->add($node);
        }
    }
```

It creates a query like this:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM `directoryprogramme` c 
WHERE `c`.`presenters` = 1234
OR `c`.`staff` = 1234
ORDER BY `name` ASC
```

The problem is that the presenters column stores comma seperated values so in reality it looks like this

```
presenters
1234,7738,5097,5100
```

and so for any `query` where the `c.presenters` equals any value that is not first in this column it returns no results. I am wondering if there is a way I can query so that it checks the entire `String`?

Comment: You never, ever store coma separated strings to your database, if you need to query it. It's logical. This is a clear indication your data model is wrong, completely. If you need to link those presenters to a program, you don't do it by adding them comma separated to a column. You do it by having a table that accepts presenter_id as a row. Then you use joins and this whole ordeal becomes incredibly simple.

Comment: You need a better database design as @N.B. mentioned.

Comment: I should point out that this db design is not the work of myself and ideally an entire rebuild of the db would be the best solution, unfortunately due to constraints with time and funding it is not possible as a result I am trying to patch issues like this one in the simplest fashion until a later date

Comment: There's ever time for patches but never for doing it right. I know this situation too ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to find your value in the list:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM `directoryprogramme` c 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1234',`c`.`presenters`) > 0
OR `c`.`staff` = 1234
ORDER BY `name` ASC
```

**Remark**

Consider normalizing your table design, if you can. This means a separate table for the presenters ids with one row per id.

Comment: Worth pointing out that FIND_IN_SET() is an inefficient workround, because it can't be index-searched in any way, so it will be slow

Comment: @MarkBaker That's very true. And it's not fun to write OR expressions instead of an WHERE presenters IN (SELECT ...), and many other problems more.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
SELECT c.* FROM `directoryprogramme` c WHERE `c`.`presenters` LIKE '%1234%' OR `c`.`staff` = 1234 ORDER BY `name` ASC
```

I believe the presenters column is in varchar.